# Live click won't work

Tags: jquery, html

So the live function isn't working, but this also does not work with `.click(function(e){`.

It's starting to become frustrating since the class is right, but it's just not recognising the click. Help?

[UPDATED] JavaScript: (Switched .live() to .on() but still no success)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

$('.pch').on('click', function(e){ 
 e.preventDefault();
alert('hi');
});

});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<a id="nava" onclick="changeTitle('ReQwire - Home');" href="home" jsload="/slideshow.php" class="notactive pch">
<img id="navaa" src="/graphics/icons/navhome.png" />
<div style="display:none;margin-top:-1px;" id="navab">Home</div>
</a>
```

Working code thanks to Anton:

```
$(document).on('click','.pch',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('hi');
});
```

Comment: Look in the console and you'll see your syntax error.

Comment: `this` should be a reserved word. use `$this` instead. also live is deprecated in the newer versions of `jQuery`

Comment: 1st thing is you shouldn't use live function : As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

Comment: in latest versions `.live` method is deprecated, use `.on` instead

Comment: Use `.on()`, `.live()` is deprecated.

Comment: SyntaxError: missing variable name
[Break On This Error]  

var this = $(this);

Comment: Consider naming your attribute `data-jsload` and getting the data using $(this).data('jsload') rather than using a non-standard attribute. Also, attach all of your event handlers using jQuery rather than having the inline `onclick` and attaching with jQuery.

Comment: The onclick was just makeshift while I work on a javascript push state function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Consider using .on() live is deprecated in the new versions of
   jQuery.
2. Have you called the jQuery script before using the function?
3. Is the item added dynamically you need to delegate on to the closest
   static element like this

   ```
   $(document).on('click','.pch',function(){
       //Code here
   });
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot name a variable `this`, it's a reserved word.  Use a different variable name.

```
var $this = $(this);
```

---

Also, `.live` is deprecated (and possibly even removed) in the latest jQuery versions.  You should use a different method to attach your event.

`.on` is the method you want to use for all your event handling needs, but it's not as simple as changing `.live` to `.on`.  The syntax is slightly different.

If the `.pch` element(s) exists at page load, and others won't be added after that you can use `.click,` (or `.on('click`).

```
$('.pch').on('click', function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('hi');
});
```

OR

```
$('.pch').click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('hi');
});
```

If you need the event to bind to elements added after page load, you need to use the "delegate" syntax for `.on`.

```
$(document).on('click', '.pch', function(){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('hi');
});
```

Instead of `$(document)`, you can (and should) use the closest parent element that's static (won't be added/removed after page load).

Comment: This post is basically what Anton said, but mucho gracias on the information brother. :)

Answer (score 0):

.live() is deprecated since jQuery 1.8, use .on() instead.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: The syntax for `.on` is different, you can't just change `.live` to `.on` and expect it to work the same way.

Comment: You're right.. I don't usually answer with full code to encourage copy-pasters. I give direction and they have to figure it out by themselves.

Comment: I agree, but you should explain that the syntax is different or at least link to the docs.

Comment: Agreed.. changed my answer.